# Disabling Radio button dynamically and getting error because of accessing column data in database

Tags: mysql, ruby

```
<%= pollTable.question %>
```

**This is giving error when the "question" column value is nil**

```
<% options.each_with_index do |option,i| 
      <%= radio_button_tag "options_id[#{poll.id}]",option.id%>
<%end%>
```

**Here i have to disable the radio button**

Comment: This looks like two separate questions.

Comment: yes...but im using both in single page.so i posted like this

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you ask one question at a time.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion #Meier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `pollTable.try(:question)` while accessing a column's value.

and coming to that radio button, you have to use ":disabled=>true"

like

```
<%=radio_button_tag "options_id[{poll.id}]",option.id,:disabled=>true%>
```

Hope, this helps